# Can I change type checking infractions from red errors to yellow warnings (or something else)?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typechecking

[Type checking in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript) reports infractions at the bottom of the screen, as errors in red ([screenshot](http://imagizer.imageshack.com/a/img923/2410/UW433J.jpg)).  Is there a way to change this to another type of notification (in another color) like warning or information (as in [this screenshot](http://imagizer.imageshack.com/a/img923/3844/EVrgMv.jpg))?

Thanks.

Comment: ...you are aware that typescript won't compile if you don't fix these, right?

Comment: I don’t know much about TypeScript.  I can say that this script will indeed compile, regardless of whether I fix these infractions or not.  My motivation behind this is that I we’ve been asked to add JSDoc block tags to our functions, complete with type definitions for the function parameters.  As I understand, VSCode’s type checking feature uses TypeScript to read these tags, and report the infractions to VSCode’s Problems panel.  To me, this looks like a useful way to help improve my programming.

Comment: But again, since these are not infractions that can crash my code in any way, I’d like to change their color from red to yellow (or something else).  We weren't told by management *why* to add the JSDoc block tags.  My educated guess is that it might be related to documentation of our API.

Comment: Our project itself does not have TypeScript installed--it seems to be that VSCode is using TypeScript to check my project's JSDoc block tags.  Would that seem like an accurate assessment?  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posed this question to the VSCode GitHub repo.  I was told his is a (relatively) long-standing open issue by now, which doesn't look to be addressed any time soon ([see here](http://300%20baht%20a%20strip%20for%20300mg)).